# Crawling facebook for art/statiatic purpose

Tags: facebook, web-crawler

I'm currently working of a project involving bots that crawl facebook to create a "neural map" of the connection between users and pages and i had some worries about legality.

Considering:

- no information is saved or distributed from profiles
- bots are polite (no spam, human-like delays between requests, etc)
- the final outcome will be more of a visual representation of the
  network

I've done a lot of researches around this problematic, but every question/answer revolves around saving data and making it publicly availlable while i do not save any data nor distribute any data.

Could i get in hot water for doing such project? Or at worst will i get asked to stop?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Facebooks does not allow it.

Comment: I am aware they don't. Not a lot of platform would. I dont care if bots get banned, i care if it would be legaly febrile despite the fact im not accumulating data from users